# Remove PDF annotations via command line

Tags: pdf, command-line, annotations

Is there a way to remove all PDF annotations (including highlights, comments, notes, arrows) in bulk (e.g., via command line)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following [series of commands](https://gist.github.com/stefanschmidt/5248592) solved my problem:

```
pdftk in.pdf output - uncompress | sed '/^\/Annots/d' | pdftk - output out.pdf compress
```

Thanks [@Farid Cheragi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407737/farid-cheraghi) for the oneliner!

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, with the following modifications for `macos`: the `sed` command should be `LANG=C LC_ALL=C sed ...` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584470/4970632)), and `pdftk` should be downloaded via the `.pkg` file linked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814799/4970632).

Comment: A faster (in-memory) way is to use a shell pipeline:

```sh
pdftk in.pdf output - uncompress | sed '/^\/Annots/d' | pdftk - output out.pdf compress
```

Comment: @FaridCheraghi it works on macOS M1. Very good

Answer (score 4):

[pdfcpu](https://pdfcpu.io/) has a [subcommand](https://pdfcpu.io/annot/annot) to remove annotations:

`pdfcpu annotations remove my.pdf`