# How do I pipe pdf-generating output through pdftk to remove annotations?

Tags: bash, applescript, pdftk

I want to pipe pdf-generating output through pdftk to remove annotations.

How can I combine this existing portion of a working AppleScript line:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/$pdf-generating-app --page-size=A4 --page-margin=5mm " & (quoted form of POSIX path of filename) & " -o " & (quoted form of POSIX path of outputFilename)
```

And have that piped through pdftk to remove annotations, as per [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598797/remove-pdf-annotations-via-command-line#comment113338121_49614525) by [Farid Cheraghi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407737/farid-cheraghi?tab=profile)?

```
sh pdftk in.pdf output - uncompress | sed '/^\/Annots/d' | pdftk - output out.pdf compress
```

Comment: If you find Prince useful, please consider purchasing a license! We rely on the support of our customers to allow us to continue working on Prince in the future. If you need a license for non-commercial or academic use, just contact us.

Comment: I've edited my question to be less-specific. For what it's worth, I'm just a hobbyist and I need to remove the annotation to make another part of my workflow work (populating PDF annotations in Finder comments). Visually, the symbol is not obstructive and is actually nice-looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's YeLogic prince, you can use the hyphen (`-`) to make it output to `stdout`and thus pipe it to pdftk :

```sh
/usr/local/bin/prince --page-size=A4 --page-margin=5mm <your filename> -o - | \
pdftk - output - uncompress | sed '/^\/Annots/d' | pdftk - output out.pdf compress
```

With AppleScript, that should be :

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/prince --page-size=A4 --page-margin=5mm " & (quoted form of POSIX path of filename) & " -o - | pdftk - output - uncompress | sed '/^\/Annots/d' | pdftk - output " & (quoted form of POSIX path of outputFilename) & " compress"
```

Anyway, i suggest you to remove the watermark directly with prince, it should be possible through CSS properties.

Comment: Yes, this did it. Thank you for the explanation and the solution. So that the AppleScript would compile, I needed to add a backslash in the sed portion:
`| sed '/^\\/Annots/d' |`
I also neglected to include my full path to pdftk in my request.

Comment: Re. removing the watermark directly, I'm using the free version of PrinceXML. According to their website, the watermark cannot be disabled on the free version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final version, mostly compiled by Zilog80, that is working for me:

`do shell script "/usr/local/bin/$pdf-generating-app --page-size=A4 --page-margin=5mm " & (quoted form of POSIX path of filename) & " -o - | /usr/local/bin/pdftk - output - uncompress | sed '/^\\/Annots/d' | /usr/local/bin/pdftk - output " & (quoted form of POSIX path of outputFilename) & " compress"`